# Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed

Tags: android, xml, dom

I know why I get this message, because the server gave an error and didn't return an XML, but just an error message. Is there a way to check if it's a valid XML, so I'm not getting this message.

I pass the XML to this method:

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straightforward, your XML looks like (example):

```
<root-element>
    ...
</root-element>
<root-element>
    ...
</root-element>
...
<root-element>
    ...
</root-element>
```

while XML allows only ONE root element, so you need to create a "wrapper" element for all your "base" elements in order for the parser to work.

Comment: Hi, the reason it gave the error is because normally an XML is passed and it works fine. But now it just gives an error message of a few lines without any XML format. I can't change the response, so I would like to check if I'm passing a valid XML string to this method or is there a way to catch this error?

Comment: When I said that last sentence, I thought, of course I should just catch the DomException..

Comment: @Diego you're right, I guess you can catch an exception and return a null document in that scenario.